# Phone log shows numbers not Exchange Contact Names

Tags: contacts, exchange, task-management

Just got my Galaxy S3 and like it so far, but they have changed so much around.

Problem= The phone syncs with my Exchange contacts list, but when I receive a call and when I look at the log list, only the number shows, no name or any other info. Sprint people couldn't help.

Also, would have been helpful if they had a sheet to show the new way to navigate to to the previous Android feature. Like the App manager, it was a widget so you could end apps that were no longer being used. I can't find that feature anywhere.

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one post. Please separate your questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are a vast multitude of app manager apps in the play store. I use the Android System Info app but it does more than just management.

As for your exchange issue what are you using to sync? I know the Android pre-installed has issues with exchange depending on how the server is setup and each version has different quirks. You may try using Touchdown to see if it will get all of your contact information into the phone, however it is only a free trial and I believe $20 after that.